# Vue Test Utils - Data persists between tests

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I try to figure out how to start every test with fresh data, but I can't seem to make it work.

That's one of my test files:

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VueFormGenerator from 'vue-form-generator'
import CustomerDetailsTabGroups from '@/modules/customer/view/component/CustomerDetailsTabGroups.vue'
import { customerMock } from './mocks/customerMock'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueFormGenerator)

const localVue = createLocalVue()

function createConfig (overrides) {
  let vuetify = new Vuetify()
  const config = {
    localVue,
    vuetify,
    mocks: {
      $translate: (msg) => msg
    },
    data: () => {
      return {
        schema: {},
        customerData: customerMock,
        groups: [
          {
            id: '111',
            name: 'Gruppe1',
            mainGroup: false
          },
          {
            id: '222',
            name: 'Gruppe2',
            mainGroup: false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    propsData: {
      customer: customerMock,
      tabIndex: 1
    },
    sync: false
  }
  return overrides ? Object.assign(config, overrides) : config
}

describe('CustomerDetailsTabGroups.vue', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(CustomerDetailsTabGroups, createConfig(null))
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.destroy()
    wrapper = null
  })

  test('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  test('watcher assign customer to customerData', async () => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(CustomerDetailsTabGroups, createConfig({
      propsData: {
        customer: { id: 'test' },
        tabIndex: 1
      }
    }))
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.customerData.id).toEqual('test')
  })

  test('addGroupToCustomer adds group to customer.customerGroups, sets mainGroup if no other mainGroup present and ' +
    'removes group from groups', () => {
    wrapper.vm.$data.customerData.customerGroups[0].mainGroup = false
    const castedWrapper = wrapper.vm as any
    castedWrapper.addGroupToCustomer(wrapper.vm.$data.groups[0])
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.customerData.customerGroups.length).toEqual(2)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.customerData.customerGroups[1].mainGroup).toBeTruthy()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.groups.length).toEqual(1)
  })

  test('removeGroupFromCustomer removes group from customer.customerGroups, sets first customerGroup.mainGroup ' +
    'true if no other mainGroup present and adds group to groups', async () => {
    await localVue.nextTick()
    const castedWrapper = wrapper.vm as any
    castedWrapper.addGroupToCustomer(wrapper.vm.$data.groups[0])
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.groups.length).toEqual(1)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.customerData.customerGroups.length).toEqual(2)
    castedWrapper.removeGroupFromCustomer(wrapper.vm.$data.customerData.customerGroups[0])
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.customerData.customerGroups.length).toEqual(1)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.customerData.customerGroups[0].mainGroup).toBeTruthy()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.groups.length).toEqual(2)
  })
})
```

And that's the component I try to test:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import customerMixin from '@/modules/customer/mixins/customerMixin'
import { Customer, CustomerGroup } from '@/modules/customer/type/types'
import {
  QUERY_CUSTOMER_GROUPS,
  QUERY_CUSTOMER_GROUPS_BY_ID
} from '@/modules/customer/graphql/queries'
import OverflowTooltip from '@/components/OverflowTooltip.vue'
import Event from '@/enum/event'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'CustomerDetailsTabData',
  mixins: [customerMixin],
  components: {
    OverflowTooltip
  },
  props: {
    customer: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    tabIndex: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      customerData: { customerGroups: [] } as Customer,
      groups: {}
    }
  },

  watch: {
    customer: {
      immediate: true,
      handler (customer: Customer): void {
        this.customerData = customer
        if (!this.customerData.customerGroups) {
          this.customerData.customerGroups = []
        }
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addGroupToCustomer (groupToAdd: CustomerGroup): void {
      const customerMainGroup = this.customerData.customerGroups.find(group => group.mainGroup)
      groupToAdd.mainGroup = this.customerData.customerGroups.length === 0 || !customerMainGroup
      this.$set(this.customerData.customerGroups, this.customerData.customerGroups.length, groupToAdd)
      this.groups = this.groups.filter(group => group.id !== groupToAdd.id)
    },

    removeGroupFromCustomer (groupToRemove: CustomerGroup): void {
      this.customerData.customerGroups = this.customerData.customerGroups.filter(group => group.id !== groupToRemove.id)
      if (groupToRemove.mainGroup && this.customerData.customerGroups.length > 0) {
        this.changeSelectedMainGroup(this.customerData.customerGroups[0])
        groupToRemove.mainGroup = false
      }
      this.$set(this.groups, this.groups.length, groupToRemove)
      this.groups.sort((group1, group2) => group1.id - group2.id)
    },

    changeSelectedMainGroup (clickedGroup: CustomerGroup): void {
      this.customerData.customerGroups.forEach(group => {
        group.mainGroup = group.id === clickedGroup.id
      })
    }
  }
})
```

No matter what I try, test 4 failes cause it has groups from previous tests. Thought wrapper.destroy() and wrapper = null would erase the data between them, but doesn't work.
Would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh, for everyone facing the same problem, I found my problem. It was not that the wrapper hasn't been recreated everytime with fresh data. That worked. My problem was, that i directly bound my mocks to the tests and they changed the mock itself, so after every test the mock had different data.
For me JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mock))) the mocks did the trick.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you fixed this?

Comment: It's a while ago and I'm don't have the source code anymore. But I'm pretty sure it was quite exactly just what I wrote in this answer.
In the function '''createConfig''' where I assigned the mock to the data attribute:
'''customerData: customerMock'''
I just created a copy without reference to the original mock:
'''customerData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(customerMock))'''
This way, in the beforeEach:
''' beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(CustomerDetailsTabGroups, createConfig(null))
  })'''
customData === customerMock for every test, without changes from previous tests.